# How to make it fast the display result in Search in textbox MORE THAN 60000 rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have Excel Database which i just want to input only the tag number and i will automatic display the result in textbox... but in takes 30sec to display the result

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
x = Sheets("Clients").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For y = 1 To x
If Sheets("Clients").Cells(y, 1).Text = TextBox1.Value Then

TextBox1.Text = Sheets("Clients").Cells(y, 1)
TextBox4.Text = Sheets("Clients").Cells(y, 3)
TextBox5.Text = Sheets("Clients").Cells(y, 4)
TextBox10.Text = Sheets("Clients").Cells(y, 5)
TextBox11.Text = Sheets("Clients").Cells(y, 6)
TextBox12.Text = Sheets("Clients").Cells(y, 7)
TextBox13.Text = Sheets("Clients").Cells(y, 8)
End If
Next y
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

`Match` is pretty fast

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()
    Dim m As VARIANT


    With Sheets("Clients")
        m = Application.Match(TextBox1.Value, .Columns(1), 0)
        If not iserror(m) then
            TextBox4.Text = .Cells(m, 3)
            TextBox4.Text = .Cells(m, 4)
            'etc
        end if
    end with

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Looping through 60,000 rows of data will be slow. Why don't you try Range.Find() instead? The documentation is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

A sample code from that page is

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500") 
    Set c = .Find(2, lookin:=xlValues) 
    If Not c Is Nothing Then 
        firstAddress = c.Address 
        Do 
            c.Value = 5 
            Set c = .FindNext(c) 
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    End If 
End With
```

In your code you could do something like the following. Declare a range variable and set it to the result of the find command. From the found range you can offset to the desired columns to retrieve their values.

```
dim result as range
x = Sheets("Clients").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
set result = Sheets("Clients").Range("A1:A" & x).Find(TextBox1.Value, lookin:=xlValues)
if not result is nothing then
   TextBox1.Text = result.value
   TextBox4.Text = result.offset(0,2).value
' and so on. use offset to get results from other columns in the row where the found range is
end if
```

Comment: but i want to display all the result in textbox is it possible to fasten the searching?

Comment: Set result = Sheets("Clients").Range("A1:K56206" & x).Find(TextBox1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues) im having an error in this code?

Comment: Just noticed the `firstaddress=c.address` is redundant in that code. It's only useful if you're not changing the found value and using `Loop While c.address<>firstaddress`.

Comment: @markangelobaccay Remove the 56206 from your code. Should just be `"A1:K" & x`

Comment: Search only in column A, not in A to K.

Comment: thank teyleyn one more thing.. how about if i enter the search code and then record the data still there so if there is duplicate no need for me to type it again>